# Parse relation query

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

After successfully adding an object to a Parse.Relation using

```
1 this.topic.relation("friend").add(email);
2 this.topic.save();
```

I'm getting `Parse.Object._getSubclass requires a string argument` on line 1 below

```
1 renderAllFriends: function(collection, filter) {
2   this.topic.relation("friend").query().find({
3     success:function(emails) {
4       this.$("#friends-list").html("");
5       emails.each(this.renderOneFriend);
6     }
7   });
8 }
```

Everything seems properly recorded in Mongo. One thing to note is that the Email object is a custom class with a non-mandatory user column.

Thanks for any tips on where to dig for an answer! The Parse repo was not that helpful in this regard since _getSubclass makes no exception for Parse.Relation (which is good).

Gon

Comment: Hi Gon, can you log the value of this.topic? You can use console.log(this.topic) as the first line in the renderAllFriends function. I think the cached this.topic instance is not in sync with the server-side object which has information about this relation.

Comment: This.topic still logs as an object `d.hasOwnProperty.f` in the init method line `this.topic = this.options.topic;` but then when it is read again in the renderAllFriends() method it's logging as `[object Object]` and `[object HTMLDivElement]` after `this.topic.fetch` succeeds.

Comment: [object Object] is actually fine, and has everything in it including the object attributes and relation.. Yet fetching it from server using `var topicQuery = new Parse.Query(Topic);
 topicQuery.get(this.topicId, {success: function(result){...` still gives me the same error on the `result.relation("friend").query().find({` line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some bugs in the early version of the parse js sdk, where the queries weren't constructed right.  If you grab the latest version of the SDK which is 1.0.10, it should work.

Comment: Thanks!! ie always make sure your script referencing in the <head> is always the latest Parse SDK `<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.0.10.min.js"></script>`